# Eclipse goto label not working in C

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, goto

I am using the Eclipse CDT and I have a `goto` label and a FILE definition after it and when I compile the project it gives me the error: `Expression expected before FILE`.

Thanks in advance,
    Mr. Man

EDIT:

Ok, so this is what I get from the command line:

```
iOS.c: In function ‘main’:
iOS.c:45: error: expected expression before ‘FILE’
iOS.c:49: error: ‘preFile’ undeclared (first use in this function)
iOS.c:49: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
iOS.c:49: error: for each function it appears in.)`
```

And this is what code throws the error:

```
fileExists:

FILE *preFile = fopen("prefix.txt","r");
```

Comment: Does it compile using the command-line? Please post a code-snippet that duplicates the error.

Comment: @Mr Man: edit your question and include the source code, command line and error messages - don't post additions to your question as comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're coding in C, you need to declare the variable at the beginning of the function:

```
void foo()
{
  FILE* preFile;

  // some code

  fileExists:
  preFile = fopen("prefix.txt","r");
}
```